# exclude urls regex

Tags: regex

Is there a way in regex to exclude some url values from a specific domain?

I want to exclude the `/` and say `/subdomaine1/...`

This worked for the subdomaine: `\/(?!subdomaine1).*` but I cant figure out how to exclude the index `/` (**homepage**)  with it. 
so for example:

domaine.com/ => false (this is the homepage)

domaine.com/aaa =>true

domaine.com/subdomaine1 =>false

domaine.com/subdomaine1/a =>false

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you're looking for? I'm unclear what you mean when you say: "I cant figure out how to include the index `/` (**homepage**) with it.

Comment: I added some explanation

Comment: Negative lookaheads are not availabe in most regex dialects.  Which application are you trying to use?  Please [edit] your question to add details as outlined in the [regex tag wiki](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/regex/info).  Thanks.

Comment: I can't get  what you want. Where is homepage in example?

Comment: @GiorgiNakeuri the homepage is the one with domaine.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your language allows negative lookaheads. If all you want to do is *not* match: "domaine.com/" you can simply do:

```
 domaine\.com\/(?!subdomaine1).+
```

[[Live Example](https://regex101.com/r/hJ4hM6/2)]

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work, **if** I understand your requirements correctly:

```
/^domaine\.com(?!\/$|\/subdomaine1).+$/
```

https://regex101.com/r/iT4gM7/3

Comment: That's the opposite of what he wants. He wants to exclude "subdomaine1"

Comment: @Florian thanks! but what I want is to excldue those

Comment: @callback I updated it so it uses a *negative lookahead*, does this fit better?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to be sure that there is subdomain then you can add additional positive lookahead. This can be spelled as: right after `domaine.com/` there should not be `subdomaine1` but there should be some word character:

```
^domaine\.com\/(?!subdomaine1)(?=\w).*$
```

https://regex101.com/r/iT4gM7/5

This can be optimized to use + instead of lookahead but then it becomes exactly as in @Jonathan's answer. But I will leave this for education purposes.

Comment: Do you think @Jonathan's answer should be accepted instead?

Comment: Yes it should, because it performs better.